# Remove microphone noise ubuntu 13.10

Tags: microphone, recordmydesktop, noise

I had windows 8 and I was using Camtasia to record my screen and my voice via a microphone. The quality of voice was well. I just migrated to Ubuntu 13.10 and tried RecordMyScreen and Kazam to record screen. But the quality of sound is bad and has a lot of noises. How can I solve that? My laptop model is NSpiron 5010

Comment: Close voters, please see http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7422/169736

Comment: I have really crackly audio in 13.04, did you have it in 13.04 as well?

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author for 7 years.